# What happen if we initialize all member of union at the same time?

Tags: c

If it happens and we initialize the union with two values I know that it will take the int number but I really want to know what happens behind the scenes

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union  x
{
    int y;
    char x[6];
};

int main(void)
{
    union x  first={4,"AAAAAA"};
    printf("%d\n",first.y);
    printf("%s\n",first.x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Your `typedef` is useless. Have you tried to compile this?

Comment: Do you realize your question is asking, "What happens if we do something that's not part of the C programming language"?  By definition, you simply can not initialize a union to have more than one value simultaneously because, by definition, a union can contain only one type of value at any one time.

Comment: "if it happen and ..." -> is a false premise because "it" (initialize all member of union at the same time) is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Did this compile? it should not. the memory allocated will be written over for every time you repurpose the union.
You can define a union with many members, but only one member can contain a value at any given time. Unions provide an efficient way of using the same memory location for multiple-purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question should not compile without at least a diagnostic about 'too many initializers' for the union variable.  You might also get a warning about a `useless storage class specifier in empty declaration` because the `typedef` doesn't actually define an alias for `union x`.

Suppose you revised the code to use designated initializers, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union x
{
    int y;
    char x[6];
};

int main(void)
{
    union x  first = { .y = 4, .x = "AAAAA" };
    printf("%d\n", first.y);
    printf("%s\n", first.x);
    return 0;
}
```

This would compile and run, but with the compiler set to fussy, you might get warnings like `warning: initialized field overwritten [-Woverride-init]`.

Note that there is one less `A` in the initializer for `.x` shown above than in the original. That ensures that the value is a (null-terminated) string, not just an array of bytes.  In this context, the designated initializer for `.x` overrides the designated initializer for `.y`, and therefore the value in `.x` is fully valid.  The output I got, for example, was:

```
1094795585
AAAAA
```

The decimal number corresponds to hex `0x41414141` as might be expected.

Note that I removed the pointless `typedef`.  My default compilation rules wouldn't accept the code; I had to cancel `-Werror` and `-Wextra` options to get it to compile.  The original code compiled with warnings without the `-Werror` to convert the warnings into error.  Even adding `-pedantic` didn't trigger an error for the extra initializer (though the warning was always given, as required by the standard).